# Not the usual "8 5 4 9 1 7 6 3 2 0" sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

This is not the usual $8, 5, 4, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 2, 0$ sequence puzzle, which the answer of the pattern is

> Numbers are in alphabetical order

The sequence is: $3, 9, 1, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 8, 6$. Can you figure the pattern of this sequence?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> It's in alphabetical order by the last letter. E, E, E, E, N, O, O, R, T, X

Comment: Isn't that ambiguous? I think the correct answer is that they are in alphabetical order when written backwards.

Comment: That is also true, but I think my answer is acceptable as well. :P

Comment: But it doesn't differentiate the sequence from, say, the same sequence with the first four numbers rearranged in a different order.

Comment: Well in that case, neither does writing each number backwards differentiate the original sequence from another sequence that has the first four numbers mixed.

Comment: The second sequence has the property that the last letters of its numbers are in alphabetical order, but not the property that its numbers are in alphabetical order when written backward.

Comment: Hello, try to explain more details, like that first 4 numbers.

Comment: I see what you are saying now...

Comment: @noedne has the solution in his comment.... for the more details

Comment: @u_ndefined - sorry don't understand your comment - but it is not a big issue. - nice question.

Answer (score 0):

Observation (not full answer):

> first 5 numbers are odd, last 5 are even.